# Not getting output there is no error what i am doing wrong

Tags: java

```
package com.db;
public class CountAlpha {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str[] = {"aaaa4bbb3c"};
        int count =0;

        for(int i =0;i<str.length;i++) {

            for(int j = i+1;j<str.length;j++) {

                if(str[i] == str[j]) {
                    count++;
                    System.out.println(str[i]+" "+count);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(str[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong in this code? I want to count the **occurance of alphabete**

Comment: use `if (str[i].equals(str[j])) {` to compare Strings

Comment: and note that you have only element in your array so the second loop will not ever evaluated

Comment: Thank a lot for help

Answer (score 1):

Here, `str` is an array with only one element in it.  So `str.length` is `1`.

So the only value that `i` ever takes is `0`.  And the inner loop is never entered at all, because `j` starts at `1`, which is already not `< str.length`.

Comment: @YCF_L What she really wants to do is compare characters, so she needs `charAt`, but doesn't need `equals`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate over an string array that has just one element. You can either use `charAt()` or you can convert your string to a char array and iterate over it:

```
String string = "aaaa4bbb3c";
char str[] = string.toCharArray();
```

Comment: Please consider upvoting/accepting the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Dawood, the inner for-loop is never executed and therefore you don't see any output. If you want to count the occurrences of letters in a given string you can do the following

```
// Store the input string in a variable of type String rather than storing in an array of String
String s = "aaaa4bbb3c";

// Convert the String to a character array so that you can loop over it easily
char[] carray = s.toCharArray();

// Declare an array to store count of each alphabet in the string
int countArray[] = new int[MAX_CHAR];
```

Loop over the characters of carray and increment count of corresponding alphabet in the countArray.

You can find complete implementation of the problem [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-count-occurrences-character/)

Answer (score 0):

The `Str` is an array with a length of `1`, so the inner `for` loop will not be excuted.

To count the occurance of characters, you can creat an array with length of 26, and iterate the String while update the count array.